# Implementing dotted progress bar in Salesforce using lightning aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-progressindicator, lightning-progressstep

I am looking for implementation of progress bar using lightning aura components in below fashion:

[image]

We have an object with a picklist containing stages(or steps). On completion of each stage we want to display the progress with that many dots filled and remaining dots as blank. We want its implementation in such a way that it can be reusable for any record with n number of stages/steps and varying stage/step names. Any pointers on how to implement this functionality/code sample would be very helpful. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You need to look this `lightning:progressIndicator.`

Official documentation -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:progressIndicator/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleProgressIndicator

SLDS documentation  - https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-indicator/